# How to prevent onmouseover event from activating the onmouseout event for its parent?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a simple menu which is initiated when the user hovers over the button on the top bar. The menu presents itself inside a container div (a block display is activated using the onmouseover event). However, when a user would hover on the menu item-list inside the container, the div goes away. The HTML structure is like:

```
<div id="menu-contaier" onmouseout="hideMenu();">
        <div id="lvl1"></div>
        <div id="lvl2"></div>
        <div id="lvl3"></div>
</div>
```

As far as my mind goes, I think this happens because when the mouse touches the "lvl1" (or lvl2 or lvl3) id, it goes out of "menu-container" div. I have tried to nest it inside of another div but did not work either.

Ideally, the HTML structure would look like this:

```
<div id="menu-contaier" onmouseout="hideMenu();">
        <div id="lvl1"><ul><li onmouseover="presentForLevel2(3, 'lvl2');">Windows</li><li onmouseover="presentForLevel2(4, 'lvl2');">Tables</li></ul></div>
        <div id="lvl2"></div>
        <div id="lvl3"></div>
</div>
```

And on hover, the 'presentForLevel2()' function will fill the lvl2 div which does not happen .

Answer (score -1):

This occurs because when you move your mouse out of any of the 'lvl' divs, the mouseout event bubbles and is triggered on the parent div also. To prevent this, set a mouseout event handler on the child divs and stop the event from bubbling. Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ESBYw/